# How to avoid Containers in listeners?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am using a class (let us call it `ClientImpl`) which listens to a socket for messages and then updates a listener to let `ClientImpl` know that a message have arrived to the socket. The listener is not implemented inside `ClientImpl`, but is passed from the classes using `ClientImpl`. Let us call my class `ClientUser` to make the problem easier to discuss. An important thing to note is that the `ClientUser` has the ownership of the listener.

So to the problem: when a message arrives I want to process it and store it to be able to read later. Since I work with a framework I cannot simply store it in a file. It has to be stored in the heap to be read later.

So the question, "Is it considered bad practice to have a container (array, Collection, ...) inside a listener?". The listener is very specific and will not be used for any other purpose. Else, are there any good options to avoid this?

I have tried to think of some options, but all these would be complicated to implement (read this as: add complexity to the code.). These ways can for example be to start a thread which continously checks for updates in a listener buffer or to make the `ClientUser` an Observer. None of these ways are very appealing. Another way would be to inject a dependency to an external Collection. I do not like either because it would create shared responsibility to handle the Collection. This is will likely cause concurrency issues.

Comment: Then what about when you receive a new message to forward to the standard event bus of your framework, if he has one of course.  Then you can have two listeners : one that log it, and the other that execute the related process. I have trouble imagine how you cannot store it in a File to be honest without knowing the technology impled.

Comment: Could you add some ideas *why* you believe that having a container inside the listener would be *bad*? Do you have **concurrency** issues? Would making the container thread-safe cause **performance** issues? From the design-patterns' point of view, listener is just an object as any other objects - the point is that it is *decoupled* from the object which generates the events.

Comment: @HonzaZidek The feeling I get about a listener would be that it should be lightweight and a container inside a listener would not make it so. As you say it might not be a big issue though. It is more about style and the other ways are not so stylish either. Anyway I am not 100% sure how much data that will be transferred, but there is a risk of performance degradation in case the container is thread-safe. I have to make some functions thread-safe, but I want to minimize the interface to the container. Anyway having a container in a listener will work. I was just looking for other ideas.Thanks!

Comment: Patrik, could you please state any arguments (yours or quoted) for that "a listener should be lightweight"?

Comment: @HonzaZidek Nope, as I said it is more of a feeling, like that a listener should be easy to setup and tear down. If a connection is started and a listener to the interface is set up (and the listener is torn down when a connection closes), then this will take more time in case the listener contains reference to a lot of data. This is Java though so the problem should not be as complicated as in for example c++. I do however not object to your opinions above. Actually I am more inclined to just add a container inside the listener for simplicity (and since I not see any practical issues).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main point of the *Listener* (or *Observer*) design pattern is to decouple the object generating events from the object reacting to the events (the *listener* / *observer*). I have not heard anything about that the listener should be lightweight.

I recommend just using the common sense. Prefer *simplicity* over *premature optimization*.

If you have **concurrency issues**, simply make the container thread-safe.

If you have **performance issues**, start thinking about optimization. **But optimize what really *is* the bottleneck**. Just keeping the container most probably will *not* be the bottleneck. Most probably it would be the message *processing* which will take the most time. Then introduce a variant of the [producer-consumer pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-pattern) - one thread just feeds a queue (this might be your listener), another thread (or thread pool) takes the messages out of the queue and processes them.

I cannot see **just having the container** in the listener as a big issue in general, unless there is a specific reason in a specific case.